# RSpec testing method missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

```
Class Abc
   def initialize(target)
    @target = target
   end

   def method_missing(name, *params, &block)
    @target.send(name, *params, &block)
  end
end
```

I have code like above, I want to write specs for above code, what could be the best way to test this.
Options 1. Test instance of `Abc` responds to a method of `@target` ?

Answer (score 3):

You should aim at testing the behavior not the implementation, so forget stubbing and expecting a particular method (unless there's literally no other way).

Also - your example is stripped out of any context. It makes little sense to have it unless it adds some value to your codebase.

But as a high level answer: ideally you'd have specs for each of the possible targets. You might consider extracting those as shared examples and do sth like this

```
RSpec.describe Abc do
  subject { described_class.new(target) }

  context 'when the target is a string' do
    let(:target) { String.new }

    it_behaves_like 'a string'
  end

  context 'when the target is a CustomUser'
    let(:target) { CustomUser.new }

    it_behaves_like 'custom user behavior'
  end
end
```

As you can see - this is boring. But I assume the `Abc` is not a real life example, so the answer is a bit abstract as well.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

- add an expectation on your target that expects a particular method
- create an instance of Abc with that target
- call the method on your abc instance